# Check for a change in value of one component and update in other component

Tags: angular

In my angular application , I am using `ng2-stomp`. In this , I am subscribing to a method (present in Global class) which will return connection status in my Dashboard component.

```
public static checkWebSocketConnectionStatus(stompObject : any, stompState : any): any{
        stompObject.state
        .map((state: number) => stompState[state])
        .subscribe((status: string) => {
            return status;
      });
    }
```

Dashboard is in `project_name/src/app/dashboard`

in dashboard component , I am calling this method and getting the status into a component variable.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

   connectionStatus : any;

   constructor(private _StompService: StompRService){
   }

   ngOnInit(){
      this.connectionStatus =  Global.checkWebSocketConnectionStatus(this._StompService,StompState)
   }

}
```

Now everytime there is a connection change from web socket, the method is called automatically and updates the `connectionStatus` variable.

Now what I want is , whenever there's a change in this `connectionStatus` variable. I want to change the value of other component variable. I have DataConnectionStatus component in another location. `src/app/shared/layout/header/data-connection-status` .

What I mean is there's no parent - child relationship between both of them. So whenever there's a change in `connectionStatus` variable of Dashboard component. I want to update `status` variable in DataConnectionStatus component.

```
export class DataConnectionStatusComponent {

    status : boolean = true;

    constructor(){
    };

    ngOnInit(){
    };

}
```

Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BehaviourSubject

in app.service.ts

```
public updatedValue: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
```

DashboardComponent.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

   connectionStatus : any;

   constructor(private _StompService: StompRService,private appService:AppService){
   }

   ngOnInit(){
      this.connectionStatus =  Global.checkWebSocketConnectionStatus(this._StompService,StompState);
      this.appService.updatedValue.next(this.connectionStatus);
   }

}
```

DataConnectionStatus component

```
export class DataConnectionStatuscomponent implements AfterViewInit{
   connectionStatus:any;
   constructor(private appService:AppService){}
      ngAfterViewInit(){
          this.appService.updatedValue.subscribe(result=>{
          if(result)
            this.connectionStatus=result;
          })
       }
}
```

Comment: When I initialized `public updatedValue: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();`. This gives me an error

Comment: Expected arguement 1 but got zero

Comment: have u imported BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: if not import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

Comment: oh sorry pass null value like this    `public updatedValue: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`

Comment: Thanks Man.... It worked. Also I made some changes on the websocketConnection method and it worked.

Comment: am glad i can help